# Unexpected result with all_touched in geocube

Tags: python, rasterio, geocube

I am using the `geocube.api.core.make_cube` function as a way to build a template array for fast data extraction in my pipeline. Basically, I will use this template array to store the row-index of a `gpd.GeoDataFrame` that overlap with each of the grids of my `da` (a `xr.DataArray`) My prior with the all_touched rasterization process is that when True, all pixels that overlap with the raster will be included, and if False, only pixels whose centroid overlaps with the geometry will be included.

In my application, I expect that if `all_touched=True`, all row-indices will appear in my template, as even small geometries will overlap with any pixel, but I found the opposite.

The testing suite does not have a good nc file, so I created a random one with the soil data in the testing suite of `geocube`:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Testing

gdf = gpd.read_file("./soil_data_flat.geojson")
gdf.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)

# Generate random array
# Get the bounds of the GeoDataFrame
bounds = gdf.total_bounds
minx, miny, maxx, maxy = bounds

# Generate a grid of longitude and latitude values
lon = np.linspace(minx, maxx, 100)
lat = np.linspace(miny, maxy, 100)

# Generate random data for the grid
data = np.random.rand(len(lat), len(lon))

# Create the DataArray
da = xr.DataArray(
    data,
    coords=[('lat', lat), ('lon', lon)],
    name='random_data'
)
da.rio.set_spatial_dims('lon', 'lat', inplace=True)
da.rio.set_crs(gdf.crs, inplace=True)
```

Now, with `all_touched=False`:

```py
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
from functools import partial
from geocube.rasterize import rasterize_image
from rasterio.enums import MergeAlg 

template = make_geocube(
    vector_data=gdf[["index", "geometry"]],
     measurements=["index"],
      like=da,
      rasterize_function=partial(rasterize_image, all_touched=False),
)

np.unique(template.index.values).shape
> (8, )
```

and with `all_touched=True`:

```py
template = make_geocube(
    vector_data=gdf[["index", "geometry"]],
     measurements=["index"],
      like=da,
      rasterize_function=partial(rasterize_image, all_touched=True),
)

np.unique(template.index.values).shape
> (7, )
```

Is this behavior expected? I am misusing the make_geocube function?